# Issue while renaming a file with file pattern in unix

Tags: unix, datastage

As part of our process, we get an input file in the .gz format. We need to unzip this file and add some suffix at the end of the file. The input file has timestamp so I am trying to use filter while unzipping and renaming this file.

**Input file name :**

```
Mem_Enrollment_20200515130341.dat.gz
```

**Step 1:**
**Unzipping this file : (working as expected)**

```
gzip -d Mem_Enrollment_*.dat.gz
```

**output :**

```
Mem_Enrollment_20200515130341.dat
```

**Step 2: Renaming this file : (issues while renaming)**

Again, I am going with the pattern but I know this won't work in this case. So, what should I do rename this file?

```
mv Mem_Enrollment_*.dat Mem_Enrollment_*.dat_D11
```

**output :**

```
Mem_Enrollment_*.dat_D11
```

**expected output :**

```
Mem_Enrollment_20200515130341.dat_D11
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
for fn in Mem_Enrollment_*.dat
do 
mv ${fn} ${fn}_D11;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With just datastage you could loop over ls output from an execute command stage via "ls Mem_Enrollment_*.dat.gz" and then use an @FM as a delimiter when looping the output list. You could then breakout the gzip and rename into two separate commands, which helps with readability in your job.

Only caveat here is that the Start Loop stage doesn't accept the @FM in the delimiter due to some internal funkyness inside Datastage. So you need to set a user variable equal to it and pass that to the mark.